# Matrix Multiplication By Rows And Columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A given matrices $A$ and $B$ produces $A\cdot B=C$.

We can say that:

1. $Col(C)=$ linear combinations of the $Col(A)$
2. $Rows(C)=$ linear combinations of the $Rows(B)$

And

3. $A\cdot[B^1 B^2...B^n]=C$
4. $[A_1 A_2... A_3]\cdot B=C$

What is the connection between 1,2 and 3,4?
(it seems to be kind of the "opposite" to each other)

Comment: @user251257 $C=0$

Comment: @user251257 Col(A) are $n \times 1$ vectors can be all 0 and same for $Col(C)$

Comment: @user251257 I do not get the point, matrices are zero dividers, so they can be nonzero and get zero

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood your notations. Sorry.

Comment: 1. and 3. say the same, the $i$-th column of $C=AB$ is the linear combination of the columns of $A$ with coefficients given by $i$-th column of $B$.